# Detecting that back pressure is happening

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

My Akka HTTP application streams some data via server-sent events, and clients can request way more events than they can handle. The code looks something like this

```
complete {
  source.filter(predicate.isMatch)
   .buffer(1000, OverflowStrategy.dropTail)
   .throttle(20, 1 second)
   .map { evt => ServerSentEvent(evt) }
}
```

Is there a way to detect the fact that a stage backpressures and somehow notify the client preferably using the same sink (by emitting a different kind of output) or if not possible just make Akka framework call some sort of callback that will deal with the fact through a control side-channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not sure I understand your use case. Are you asking about back pressure at `.buffer` or at `.throttle`? Another part of my confusion is that you are suggesting emitting a new "control" element in a situation where the stream is already back pressured. So your control element might not be received for some time. Also, if you emit a control element every single time you receive back pressure you will likely create a flood of control elements.

One way to build this (overly naive) solution would be to use [conflate](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/conflate.html).

```
  val simpleSink: Sink[String, Future[Done]] =
    Sink.foreach(e => println(s"simple: $e"))

  val cycleSource: Source[String, NotUsed] =
    Source.cycle(() => List("1", "2", "3", "4").iterator).throttle(5, 1.second)

  val conflateFlow: Flow[String, String, NotUsed] =
    Flow[String].conflate((a, b) => {
      "BACKPRESSURE CONTROL ELEMENT"
    })

  val backpressureFlow: Flow[String, String, NotUsed] =
    Flow[String]
      .buffer(10, OverflowStrategy.backpressure) throttle (2, 1.second)

  val backpressureTest =
    cycleSource.via(conflateFlow).via(backpressureFlow).to(simpleSink).run()
```

To turn this into a more usable example you could either:

1. Make some sort of call inside of `.conflate` (and then just drop one of the elements). Be careful not to do anything blocking though. Perhaps just send a message that could be de-duplicated elsewhere.
2. Write a [custom graph stage](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-customize.html). Doing something simple like this wouldn't be too difficult.

I think I'd have to understand more about the use case though. Take a look at all of the off the shelf [backpressure aware operators](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/index.html#backpressure-aware-operators) and see if one of them helps.

Comment: I guess the solution is to implement my own buffer that uses `conflate` and emit control elements with some sort of throttling